# Video with transparent background on page above image background

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, animation

I want to embed some video into my HTML page. As background I want to use big picture. And above it I want to insert loop video with (i.e.) walking man.

- So, can I embed video (without flash and any player controls) in page?
- Can I decode video with transparent background? Is there any codecs which support transparent background (alpha-channel)?

Now I see this solutions:

- Making flash (that I don't want to use)
- Create gif animation (and it will be big file size and quite bad quality)

Comment: Sounds like we're going back to 1991 animated gifs to me. Grim.

Comment: so I don't want to use them,as I don't want to use flash. Looking for modern way of embedding video in html (not only in HTML5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible with anything beyond GIF (over sized and would have a horrible border between opaque and transparent), MNG (not widely supported), and scripted SVG.

Have you thought about figuring out where in the background this video would appear and putting THAT section of the background into the video as a static background behind the man walking?

Comment: yes I've thought about putting background image in video. But it's not as flexible as I want